# php for adding data to mySQL from POST form

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have been reading every comment on this board for 4 hours in relation to troubleshooting this code. I was hoping someone can provide some kind feedback to a noob here.

```
<?php
//Join.php
define('DB_NAME', 'biblaunch');
define('DB_USER', 'xxxxxxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxxxxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxxxxxxxx.hostedresource.com');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['name'];
$value2 = $_POST['email'];
$value3 = $_POST['shirt'];


$sql = "INSERT﻿ INTO customer (name, email, shirt) VALUES ('$value', 
'$value2','$value3')";`

$result = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close();
?>
```

my HTTP/mainpage uses this form structure:

```
<form id="joinForm" action="join.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                       <fieldset>                       
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
             <label class="no">Name</label>
                 <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                                     <div class="row-fluid">
                         <div class="span12">
             <label class="no">Email</label>
             <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                 <div class="row-fluid">
                 <div class="span12">   
                     <div class="row-fluid">
    <select style="display: none;" name="shirt" class="selectpicker span12">

<option selected="selected">Select Preferred Shirt</option>

<option>Mens Style Shirt</option>       

<option>Ladies Style Shirt</option>                                            
<option>Youth/Child Shirt</option>
    </select>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
<div class="formFoot">                     
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

Thank you for all your help in advance

Comment: Apart from your question, I suggest you to move towards PDO or Mysqli.

Comment: and paste ALL your form code, where you closed your form? and where did you close the div class="formFoot"

Comment: I am looking into Mysqli and will incorporate it when I move to public use. I am aware of SQL injection attacks. Thanks for your reminder.  

However, this code still isnt working. I do get the print outs from the echo commands but nothing populates the database. I am at a loss as to what is causing the lack of population in the database. I will try to redo this again from scratch and use a simple form to see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have tried your script in my PC and found an extra single quote in query. In addition your select input was hidden in HTML file.

**Do not use Mysql api in real project as its deprecated**. Please use PDO or MYSQLi.

**Full working Example:**

```
<?php

//join.php
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');


$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value      = $_POST['name'];
$value2     = $_POST['email'];
$value3     = $_POST['shirt'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (name, email, shirt) VALUES ('$value', '$value2','$value3')";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();


?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Items</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="joinForm" action="join.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <fieldset>                       
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <label class="no">Name</label>
                    <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <label class="no">Email</label>
                    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">   
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <select style="" name="shirt" class="selectpicker span12">

                            <option selected="selected">Select Preferred Shirt</option>
                            <option>Mens Style Shirt</option>       
                            <option>Ladies Style Shirt</option>                                            
                            <option>Youth/Child Shirt</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="formFoot">                     
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this and still have the issue of it not populating the database. Iwonder if its the php or something else. I'm at a loss right now.

Comment: Anam, I will be checking this out as soon as i get home. I appreciate the amount of work and time to redo it. If it works, I am happy to either contribute via paypal or if there is something else I can do for you let me know. I am going out of my mind here. P.S. I will be using prepared statements and will have it professionally done if this ever goes public.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am a web developer. if your friend need developer you can recommend me. Please remove the word god from comment..Which country are you from?

Comment: Anam - YOU ARE AMAZING!!! THANK YOU so much this works. How can I help you, Paypal? Do you ever do any website consulting work? I may know a startup who might be interested in hiring you for some work.

I am in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

Remove character "**`**" in

```
$sql = "INSERT﻿ INTO customer (name, email, shirt) VALUES ('$value', 
'$value2','$value3')";`
```

and test again

Comment: thank you so much. I will be testing and updating this to confirm it works.

Comment: I can't believe i missed that in my error checking. 
However, I removed that character and I still dont have it populating the database. I'm wondering now if its the php or something to do with godaddy hosting/database.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra character:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (name, email, shirt) VALUES ('$value', 
'$value2','$value3')";`
```

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (name, email, shirt) VALUES ('$value', 
'$value2','$value3')";
```

Also, you are prone to SQL injection. Use `real_escape_string` on your `$_POST`

Comment: I have tried your removal of the extra character (can't believe I missed that) but it still doesnt work. Very good point about SQL injection...I will probably move to Mysqli when i go public but this is for an internal site at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You Are Having Some Syntex Problem in you code i have modified it check it

```
     <?php
  //Join.php
 define('DB_NAME', 'biblaunch');
 define('DB_USER', 'xxxxxxx');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxxxxx');
 define('DB_HOST', 'xxxxxxxxx.hostedresource.com');

  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

  if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $value = $_POST['name'];

  echo $value;

 echo '<br></br>';
 $value2 = $_POST['email'];

  echo $value2;
  $value3 = $_POST['shirt'];


  $sql = "INSERT﻿ INTO customer (name, email, shirt) VALUES      ('$value','$value2','$value3')";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  mysql_close();

 ?>
```

Comment: I have tried this code and it still doesnt work. Yes, I updated the actual passwords and all. Thanks for the help but I seem to be at a loss as to what is happening/wrong.

Comment: I have tried this code its working fine just check values you are posting.

Answer (score -1):

FIRSTLY close form tag at the last line

```
</form>
```

AND NOW REMOVE THE ` SYMBOL AT THE END OF THE QUERY

THE FOLLOWING IS THE CORRECT REPLACE IT

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (name, email, shirt) VALUES ('$value', 
'$value2','$value3')";
```

AT THE END OF THE QUERY

Comment: thank u, I forgot to include it in the snippet but the close form tag was there