# Query not working - INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, insert

So i recently starting learning PHP, and now im trying to get code into my database.
The data is input from the user through a form.

here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $blogtitle = $_POST['blogTitle'];
    $blogcategory = $_POST['blogCategory'];
    $blogcontent = $_POST['blogContent'];
    // aanmaak date van de blog
    $blogdate = date("d/m.Y"); 

    // Checkt of alle velden zijn ingevuld
    if (!empty($blogtitle) && !empty($blogcategory) && !empty($blogcontent)) {

        //echo "je zit nu bij de query";

        $addBlogQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog (blog_ID, blog_title, blog_category, blog_content, blog_date)
                                     VALUES (NULL, $blogtitle, $blogcategory, $blogcontent, blogdate )");

        if ($addBlogQuery) {
            echo "blog added successfully";
        }
        else {
            echo "something went wrong";
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->notFilledErrorAction();
    }

}
```

For some reason it's not adding any data my database. My connection to my database is working properly, and i dont see a mistake in my query.

Does someone see an error in this code? or could help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Try wrapping your variables (in the query) in `'`s

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Try this: `echo "something went wrong" . mysql_error();`

Comment: *sidenote:* your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow POST values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: Instead of echoing 'something went wron' try `echo mysql_error();`. Fix the syntax error you have in your query near 'blogdate'

Comment: @MikeW so i got the following error: "unknown column in 'field list'".. didnt know about the mysql_error.. im still new to it. Learned something new again haha.

Comment: look here `$blogcontent, blogdate )");` i think it may be like this `$blogdate`

Comment: Check out this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175434/php-for-adding-data-to-mysql-from-post-form

Comment: @BOSS This was indeed a problem :) also i forgot to add single quotes to my variables! Thx for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `INSERT` statement:

```
    $addBlogQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog (blog_ID, blog_title, blog_category, blog_content, blog_date)
                                 VALUES (NULL, $blogtitle, $blogcategory, $blogcontent, blogdate )");
                                       You are missing a $ here------------------------^
```

You also need to wrap your variables in `'` single quotes:

```
    $addBlogQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog (blog_ID, blog_title, blog_category, blog_content, blog_date)
                                 VALUES (NULL, '$blogtitle', '$blogcategory', '$blogcontent', '$blogdate' )");
```

Furthermore, the mysql_* API is now deprecated. *Please* read the big red box [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should start using MySQLi or PDO now whilst it is still relatively easy to change.

Comment: Thx! this actually fixed my problem! learned alot from this mistake! wont forget about the singe quotes anytime soon! =)

Comment: No worries, but on a serious note please do stop using mysql_query. It's a bad idea to start using a deprecated interface and PDO or MySQLi will be much better. They will also help you prevent the SQL Injection vulnerability you have in your code. There is information in the link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose strings ,date and DATETIME values with single quotes (`'`).

And you have not enclosed in your SQL.

Please modify your SQL as:

```
$addBlogQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog (blog_ID, blog_title, blog_category, blog_content, blog_date)
                                     VALUES (NULL, '$blogtitle', '$blogcategory', '$blogcontent', 'blogdate' )");
```

Comment: This fixed my problem! totally forgot about the ''.. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Mysql support only following date format:

```
YYYY-mm-dd
```

but your code has different format

```
$blogdate = date("d/m.Y");
```

Try the following:

**`$blogdate = date("Y-m-d");`**

And you have passed ID null, i think you have selected ID as primary key. primary key can not be null. if your ID field support auto-increment you don't need to pass anything.

```
$addBlogQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog (blog_title, blog_category, blog_content, blog_date)
                                     VALUES ($blogtitle, $blogcategory, $blogcontent, blogdate )");
```

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: This was not the solution to the problem. But this is new info for me, thx!! =)

Comment: why to use `date` function do you think it worth it? mysql have native support to date time ie `NOW()`  function.

Answer (score 2):

See the changes below and try again:

```
$blogdate = date("Y-m-d"); 
$addBlogQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `blog` (`blog_title`, `blog_category`, `blog_content`, `blog_date`)
                                 VALUES ('$blogtitle', '$blogcategory', '$blogcontent', '$blogdate' )");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use more secure way , Use PDO - Stop using `MYSQL_*` it's deprecated
PDO escapes itself, you doesn't need to use mysql_real_escape_string

```
<?php
 $user="root";
  $pass="";
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=databasename', $user, $pass); //establish new connection
$sql ="INSERT INTO blog (blog_ID, blog_title, blog_category, blog_content, blog_date)
                                     VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
try{
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($a, $b, $c, $d));
if($stmt->rowCount()>0){
//done
}
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
?>
```

Before inserting into database you should sanitize you data to prevent SQL injection and XSS. Use this function:

```
function sanitize($data){
    $data= htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($data)));
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following query there is no need to use php `date` function mysql has native support to date and time functions

```
INSERT INTO blog
(`title`, `category`, `content`, `date`, `id`)
VALUES
('Title here', 'category here','blog content here', NOW(), 1);
```

here is SQL test [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7205/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$addBlogQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog (blog_title, blog_category, blog_content, blog_date) VALUES ($blogtitle, $blogcategory, $blogcontent, blogdate )");
```

It seems your mistake is insert the value of `blog_id` by `NULL`. `blog_id` column is the primary key. If you insert `blog_id` by `NULL`, then the data can't push to your database. Since `blog_id` is primary key, you don't need to insert `blog_id` manually. It will automatically inserted.

Comment: Yes, blog_ID is my primary key. But you're saying i dont have to give it 'NULL' to get it automatically get its id? Right now it's working fine with the ID automatically added everytime